# ASP.NET MVC error to use $.post(), this method put another controller name to the call

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC application. I have a problem when I use `$.pos()`. This method receives in the first parameter the controller name and action name, for example `"Controller/Action"`.
The problem is that in some place for no reason the post method adds the controller name to the post method. I can observe this using *firebug*. Here's an example from my source code:

```
$.post("Customer/Create", {}, function (data) {
    $("#Detalle").html("");
    $("#Detalle").append(data);
});
```

For no reason the call contains `"Customer/Customer/Create"`. I can observe it in *firebug* and this causes an error because `"Customer/Customer/Create"` doesn't exist.
What is the problem?
I have seen that if I use `$.ajax` or `().load` I don't have this problem, but I prefer to use `$.post` instead of `$.ajax` because will cause a great change. Can someone explain to me what is cuasing the problem?
Thank you friends.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of this:

```
$.post("Customer/Create", {}, function (data) { $("#Detalle").html(""); $("#Detalle").append(data); });
```

Try this, add a slash beginning of your `url`:

```
$.post("/Customer/Create", {}, function (data) { $("#Detalle").html(""); $("#Detalle").append(data); });
```

Comment: +1 Yep, the url will be relative to the current page (Customer) without the extra leading `/`.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the slash related error or correct path best way use Url like below:

```
  $.post('@Url.Action("Create","Customer")', {}, function (data) {
            $("#Detalle").html("");
          $("#Detalle").append(data);
  });
```

or if are using expernal js file than best way to manage url .Create global variables in Layout or View like below:

```
  <Script>
    var customerUrl = {
    Create: '@Url.Action("Create","Customer")'
    //Append mor url accoring to your requirement.
   }
 </script>
```

and then in you external js file use following :

```
  $.post(customerUrl.Create , {}, function (data) {
            $("#Detalle").html("");
          $("#Detalle").append(data);
  });
```